# Proving $2^n = o(3^n)$

Tags: algorithms, logarithms, asymptotics, computational-complexity

I'm trying to prove that $2^n = o(3^n)$ using the definition of little-o alone. I'm having trouble because I can't seem to find a way to describe $n$ as a function of $c$ where $c$ is positive. Here's an example:

\begin{align}2^n &< c 3^n \\
\frac{2^n}{c} &< 3^n\\
 \log_3{\frac{2^n}{c}} &< n\\
 n\log_3{2} - \log_3{c} &< n\\
  - \log_3{c} &< n - n\log_3{2}\\
  \frac{-\log_3{c}}{1-\log_3 2} &< n,
\end{align} but LHS is negative. If I multiply $-1$ on both sides it wont help, as now $n$ is less than that term.

Am I doing something terribly wrong?

Comment: Can you give your definition of $o(3^n)$? Also note that for $c<1$, $-\log_3 c$ is actually positive

Comment: The LHS need not be negative : what if $c = 1$, for example? Also, from your calculation it is clear what function $n$ can be of $c$ : it can be $\left\lceil\frac{-\log_3 c}{1 - \log_3 2}\right\rceil + 1$, for example.

Comment: @CalvinKhor The definition I'm using is: $f(n) = o(g(n))$ means for all $c > 0$ there exists some $n_0 > 0$ such that $0 \leq f(n) < cg(n)$ for all $n ≥ n_0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Case 1: $c\ge 1$.

As $2<3$, we have (e.g. inductively) $2^n < 3^n \le c 3^n$ for all $n\ge 1 =:n_0$.

### Case 2: $0<c<1$.

Now we use your calculation to see that we can use

$$n\ge n_0 := \frac{-\log_3 c}{1-\log_3 2}. $$
Note that this quantity is positive. e.g. for $c= 1/3$, $\log_3 c = -1$ so $n_0 = \frac1{1-\log_32} > 0$, since $\log_32\approx 0.631$.

Comment: God, I feel so dumb not noticing I could split it into two cases. Thank you!

Comment: @bnoite its not required, but I think this is easier to understand. There's actually nothing wrong with getting $n>$ negative, it just means you can take every $n\ge0$ (I chose $n_0 = 1$ to fit your definition)

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $$ \frac{2^n}{3^n} = \left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^n$$

Comment: I've tried that: I always end up with $ n < \frac{\log_2{c}}{\log_2{\frac{2}{3}}} $. I need $n$ to be greater then the other term.

Comment: $\log_2\frac23\lt0$.  So your inequality flips.

Answer (score 1):

You wrote

$$(*) \quad \frac{-\log_3{c}}{1-\log_3 2} < n$$

and this is O.K !

You have to distinguish three cases:

1. $c=1$. In this case $(*)$ means $n>0.$ This is correct, since $2^n<3^n$ for all natural $n$.
2. $c<1.$ In this case $\frac{-\log_3{c}}{1-\log_3 2}>0$ and we have that $2^n<3^n$ for all $n> \frac{-\log_3{c}}{1-\log_3 2}.$
3. $c>1.$ In this case $\frac{-\log_3{c}}{1-\log_3 2}<0$ and we have $2^n<3^n$ for all natural $n$.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $f=o(g)\iff \lim_{n\to\infty}f(n)/g(n)=0$ easily, by the squeeze theorem,  say.

But it's easy to see that $2^n/3^n\to0$.

For instance,  it is a strictly decreasing sequence,  bounded beneath by $0$.  So it converges.   Call the limit $L$.  Then $2/3L=L\implies L=0$.